# Having difficulty in transforming nested json to flat json using python

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-2.7, nested

I have a below API response. This is a very small subset which I am pasting here for reference. there can be 80+ columns on this.

```
[["name","age","children","city", "info"], ["Richard Walter", "35", ["Simon", "Grace"], {"mobile":"yes","house_owner":"no"}],
["Mary", "43", ["Phil", "Marshall", "Emily"], {"mobile":"yes","house_owner":"yes", "own_stocks": "yes"}],
["Drew", "21", [], {"mobile":"yes","house_owner":"no", "investor":"yes"}]]
```

Initially I thought pandas could help here and searched accordingly but as a newbie to python/coding I was not able to get much out of it. any help or guidance is appreciated.

I am expecting output in a JSON key-value pair format such as below.

````
{"name":"Mary", "age":"43", "children":["Phil", "Marshall", "Emily"],"info_mobile":"yes","info_house_owner":"yes", "info_own_stocks": "yes"},
{"name":"Drew", "age":"21", "children":[], "info_mobile":"yes","info_house_owner":"no", "info_investor":"yes"}]```
````

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the first list always will be the headers (column names)? 
If that is the case, maybe something like this could work.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [["name", "age", "children", "info"], ["Ned", 40, ["Arya", "Rob"], {"dead": "yes", "winter is coming": "yes"}]]

headers = data[0]
data = data[1:]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
df_json = df.to_json()
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks @Atle, but with the above code the nested json/dict is being referenced under one column i,e. info. I was hoping if we can get individual columns for info as well with respective key and values.

```
  name  age     children                                            info
0  Ned   40  [Arya, Rob]  {u'winter is coming': u'yes', u'dead': u'yes'}
```

Comment: I see. Then I do not know if you can use pandas.

Comment: is there any other module present with which this can be achieved.

Comment: Not that I can think of. Why do you want to format the data in that manner?

Comment: I want the data in that format so that it can become easier to push the data into redshift postgrsql table and column mappings becomes much easier. because "info" dict key holds lot of value about any user and we don't all of that under one column because it will be hard to query on that or later create dashboards with that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first list always represents the keys `["name", "age"... etc]`
and then the subsequent lists represent the actual data/API response then you can construct a dictionary (key pair values) like this.

```
keys = ["name", "age", "children", "info"]
api_response = ["Richard Walter", "35", ["Simon", "Grace"], {"mobile":"yes","house_owner":"no"}]
data_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(keys, api_response)}
```

Comment: Thanks @Omar.
but this gives me a response as 

```
{'info': {'mobile': 'yes', 'house_owner': 'no'}, 'age': '35', 'name': 'Richard Walter', 'children': ['Simon', 'Grace']}
```
whereas I am looking for response as

```
{'info_mobile': 'yes', 'info_house_owner': 'no', 'age': '35', 'name': 'Richard Walter', 'children': ['Simon', 'Grace']}
```